# Fix the position of a View that is in the list while scrolling the same list, programmatically

Tags: android, view, scroll, android-recyclerview

Let's assume that I have an `ImageView` and a `TextView` one over the other. These two views are the first two elements of my `RecyclerView`. The other elements of the `RecyclerView` are of the same type.

> ImageView(element 0 of RecyclerView)
>
> TextView(element 1 of RecyclerView)
>
> element2
>
> element3
>
> ...

So, normally in this **scenario**, if you scroll down, `ImageView` and `TextView` will go upwards and disappear from sight as i continue scrolling. What I want is, `ImageView` to disappear by going up out of the screen, but `TextView` to stay at top of the screen, even if I scroll further, the other elements of the `RecyclerView` will go up and `TextView` will stay at a fixed position top of the screen.

> ---TextView(FIXED)---
>
> element6
>
> element7
>
> ...(scrolling)

I thought about this and couldn't find a good programmatical solution, but I realised I could do it with a little bit of cheating.

`RecyclerView` will work just like in the **scenario** I mentioned. But when `TextView` starts to leave the screen from the top, a clone `TextView` will be visible and brought in front of the `RecyclerView`, so even if my real `TextView` disappears from the screen, clone `TextView` will hold its place.

However, this solution did not satisfy me. Also I didn't try out my idea and don't know if it will work completely. I searched a nice solution for this, but I couldn't find any closely-related question.

I wonder if there's any way to achieve this behaviour without using new views or etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you looked into Sticky List Header libraries like [this](https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders)? I bet if you dove into their source code, you'd find some good inspiration.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to do what I want :)